# Structure and Code of Tornado WebAPP

Tags: python, beginner, security, tornado

I wrote a test application to familiarize myself with the `Tornado` Python framework. The application currently generates a cookie that you can view and delete. I also created a certain file structure. I would like to know if it will comply with current coding standards. Of course, I am also open to any comments about my code.

Is it appropriate to use `eval()` to run a function that is saved in a dictionary? Is there a better way to do this if I want to keep a reference to the dictionary? From my beginner's point of view, this feature should not do any harm. If I am wrong, please direct me or help me solve the problem.

If you would like to run it you have to set-up `COOKIE_SECRET_ENVIRONMENT` in your environment or simply change the `COOKIE_SECRET_VALUE` in `main.py`

**File listing:**

main.py

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

import random
import environments
import responses
import settings

from dictionaries import COOKIES_DICTIONARY
from dictionaries import REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello!")


class SetCookieHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_secure_cookie(name=COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                      max_age_days=settings.COOKIE_MAX_AGED_DAYS):
            self.set_secure_cookie(name=COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                   value=str(eval(COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['VALUE'])),
                                   expires_days=settings.COOKIE_EXPIRES_DAYS)
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_SET_UP)
            self.set_status(status_code=201,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['201'])
        else:
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_WAS_SET_UP)
            self.set_status(status_code=401,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['401'])


class GetCookieHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_secure_cookie(name=COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                  max_age_days=settings.COOKIE_MAX_AGED_DAYS):
            COOKIE_VALUE = str(self.get_secure_cookie(name=COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                                      max_age_days=settings.COOKIE_EXPIRES_DAYS), "UTF-8")
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_GET_VALUE.format(COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                                          COOKIE_VALUE))
            self.set_status(status_code=200,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['200'])
        else:
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_NOT_SET_UP)
            self.set_status(status_code=401,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['401'])


class DeleteCookieHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_secure_cookie(name=COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'],
                                  max_age_days=settings.COOKIE_MAX_AGED_DAYS):
            self.clear_cookie(COOKIES_DICTIONARY['TEST_COOKIE']['KEY'])
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_DELETED)
            self.set_status(status_code=200,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['200'])
        else:
            self.write(responses.COOKIE_NOT_SET_UP)
            self.set_status(status_code=401,
                            reason=REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY['401'])


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/set_cookie", SetCookieHandler),
        (r"/get_cookie", GetCookieHandler),
        (r"/delete_cookie", DeleteCookieHandler),

    ], cookie_secret=environments.COOKIE_SECRET_VALUE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

settings.py

```
COOKIE_MAX_AGED_DAYS = 7
COOKIE_EXPIRES_DAYS = 7
COOKIE_SECRET_ENVIRONMENT = "TORNADO_COOKIE_SECRET_VALUE"
```

reponses.py

```
COOKIE_SET_UP = "Set up"
COOKIE_NOT_SET_UP = "Not set up"
COOKIE_WAS_SET_UP = "Was set up"
COOKIE_DELETED = "Deleted"
COOKIE_GET_VALUE = "Key '{}': Value '{}'"
```

environments.py

```
import os
import settings

COOKIE_SECRET_VALUE = os.getenv(settings.COOKIE_SECRET_ENVIRONMENT)
```

dictionaries.py

```
COOKIES_DICTIONARY = {
    "TEST_COOKIE": {"KEY": "TEST_COOKIE_KEY",
                    "VALUE": "random.randint(1, 100)"},
}

REPONSE_CODE_DICTIONARY = {
    "100": "Continue",
    "101": "Switching Protocols",
    "102": "Processing",
    "200": "OK",
    "201": "Created",
    "202": "Accepted",
    "203": "Non-authoritative Information",
    "204": "No Content",
    "205": "Reset Content",
    "206": "Partial Content",
    "207": "Multi-Status",
    "208": "Already Reported",
    "226": "IM Used",
    "300": "Multiple Choices",
    "301": "Moved Permanently",
    "302": "Found",
    "303": "See Other",
    "304": "Not Modified",
    "305": "Use Proxy",
    "307": "Temporary Redirect",
    "308": "Permanent Redirect",
    "400": "Bad Request",
    "401": "Unauthorized",
    "402": "Payment Required",
    "403": "Forbidden",
    "404": "Not Found",
    "405": "Method Not Allowed",
    "406": "Not Acceptable",
    "407": "Proxy Authentication Required",
    "408": "Request Timeout",
    "409": "Conflict",
    "410": "Gone",
    "411": "Length Required",
    "412": "Precondition Failed",
    "413": "Payload Too Large",
    "414": "Request-URI Too Long",
    "415": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "416": "Requested Range Not Satisfiable",
    "417": "Expectation Failed",
    "418": "I'm a teapot",
    "421": "Misdirected Request",
    "422": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "423": "Locked",
    "424": "Failed Dependency",
    "426": "Upgrade Required",
    "428": "Precondition Required",
    "429": "Too Many Requests",
    "431": "Request Header Fields Too Large",
    "444": "Connection Closed Without Response",
    "451": "Unavailable For Legal Reasons",
    "499": "Client Closed Request",
    "500": "Internal Server Error",
    "501": "Not Implemented",
    "502": "Bad Gateway",
    "503": "Service Unavailable",
    "504": "Gateway Timeout",
    "505": "HTTP Version Not Supported",
    "506": "Variant Also Negotiates",
    "507": "Insufficient Storage",
    "508": "Loop Detected",
    "510": "Not Extended",
    "511": "Network Authentication Required",
    "599": "Network Connect Timeout Error"
}
```